# Ant calling targets several times

Tags: ant

I set up a simple Ant script to understand why my dependency targets are being called several times when I specified several targets to execute (in Eclipse):

```
<project name="test">
    <macrodef name="mkjar" description="Build a jar from 'tgt'">
        <attribute name="tgt" />
        <sequential>
            <echo message="mkjar @{tgt}" level="info" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="Common">
        <mkjar tgt="Common" />
    </target>
    <target name="Net" depends="Common">
        <mkjar tgt="Net" />
    </target>
    <target name="DB" depends="Common">
        <mkjar tgt="DB" />
    </target>
    <target name="FooBar" depends="Common,DB">
        <mkjar tgt="FooBar" />
    </target>
    <target name="FooBar2" depends="Common,Net,DB">
        <mkjar tgt="FooBar2" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Output:

```
Buildfile: buildtest.xml
Common:
     [echo] mkjar Common
Net:
     [echo] mkjar Net
DB:
     [echo] mkjar DB
FooBar2:
     [echo] mkjar FooBar2
Common:
     [echo] mkjar Common
DB:
     [echo] mkjar DB
FooBar:
     [echo] mkjar FooBar
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 283 milliseconds
```

Why is Ant going twice into targets `Common` and `DB`? I thought `macrodef` would be executed inside the same Ant flow and project scope. I tried uglier things with `antcall`

```
<target name="mkjar" unless="jar-${tgt}">
    <property name="jar-${tgt}" value="true" />
    ...
</target>
```

But it's not better (it's even creating several `jar-<tgt>` properties!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought macrodef would be executed inside the same Ant flow and project scope

It does. When you invoke `ant FooBar2 FooBar`, both targets are executed in the same Ant project. But in this case, Ant does not "track" that a dependency target has already executed when it is also a dependency for the second target.

A dependency target is invoked only once when it is in the same chain of dependencies of only one target, for example:

```
<target name="A"/>
<target name="B" depends="A"/>
<target name="C" depends="B"/>
<target name="D" depends="C,B,A"/>
```

When running `ant D`, the following chain of targets is run: `A --> B --> C --> D`.

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html for more info.

One way to solve the issue here is to add a condition on the target to skip running it when a property is set:

```
<target name="Common" unless="common.already.executed">
    <mkjar tgt="Common" />
    <property name="common.already.executed" value="true" />
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it makes sense if you consider Ant can be used for other things than compilation, in which case a target could have to be executed several times (e.g. copy/remove a file).